# asp.net get arabic text from textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, arabic

I have a table with two arabic column first_name and last_name.
if I try to get columns from database and display them in textBoxes it work perfect,
but if I try to write arabic text in textBox and get the text in server by this code: txtArabicFirstName.Text the text goes wrong like Gibberish

this is my first line in aspx page:

please help!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually post the code, which isn't helping, but I believe your issue may be the database, and more accurately how the data is being stored.

There are a couple of ways of solving the problem if that is the case:

**1. Switch your collation to one which supports Arabic character sets.**

You can find collations which support them but running the following query:

```
SELECT name, description 
FROM fn_helpcollations() 
WHERE name LIKE 'Arabic%'
```

Then go to your table or database settings and switch to a type you want.

The other option, which may be easier depending on where your issue occurs, and how many character sets you want to support, is

**2. Use `NVARCHAR` data type instead of `VARCHAR`**

`NVARCHAR` allows you to store unicode characters (like Arabic script) in your database. Do note that for each character you store it will use 2 bytes instead of 1, but you'll be able to store virtually anything you could possibly want to store.

Comment: The problem is not in the database but in the c# code.
After entering Arabic text to text box and submitting it, the textbox.text contains bad characters (before inserting text to db)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change encoding for request and response in the web.config like this:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <globalization
    fileEncoding="utf-8" 
    requestEncoding="utf-8" 
    responseEncoding="utf-8"
    culture="en-US"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For only one page

```
<configuration>
    <location path="yourfile.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
        </system.web>
    </location>
<configuration>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but when I do it all pages in my aplication get bad characters, I need just specific page with just two specific fields to be in arabic.

Comment: You can change encoding for one page and for request only, but I don't know if it possible for only some fields.Check Edits.@CheviZolti

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Butler1233 mention, Use prefix **'N'** for Unicode characters like Arabic characters like below example.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (first_name, last_name)
VALUES (N'arabic_first_name', N'arabic_last_name');
```